# Sales order address custom attribute value in Order Rest Api

Tags: magento2.3, api, rest-api, sales

I have added door number custom attribute to sales order address table. But I'm not able to get the vale in Order REST API.

Please help me on this

Comment: anyone knows the workaround

Comment: Team please suggest me a workaround

Comment: Friends it is really urgent. Please help me

Comment: any luck on this @poornima

Answer (score 1):

You have to use extension attribute to expose `door number` at reset Api.

- https://store.fooman.co.nz/blog/an-introduction-to-extension-attributes.html
- https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/extension_attributes/adding-attributes.html

Create an extension attribute on  `Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderAddressInterface` for door no field.

Create extension_attributes.xml at `app/code/{Vendorname}/{ModuleName}/etc`
and add door number is an extension attributes.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
    <extension_attributes for="Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderAddressInterface">
        <attribute code="door_no" type="string" />
    </extension_attributes>
</config>
```

**I assume that door no is varchar field at the database level.**

After that, need to expose this field to using a plugin on on `\Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface` .
 Create after plugin on method `save` .

```
<?php
namespace Vendorname\ModuleName\Plugin\Magento\Sales\Api;

use Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderAddressExtensionInterfaceFactory;
use Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderAddressExtension;
use Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderAddressInterface;

class OrderRepositoryInterface
{
    /**
     * @var OrderAddressExtensionInterfaceFactory
     */
    private $addressExtensionInterfaceFactory;

    public function __construct(
        OrderAddressExtensionInterfaceFactory $addressExtensionInterfaceFactory
    ) {
        $this->addressExtensionInterfaceFactory = $addressExtensionInterfaceFactory;
    }

    public function afterGet(
        \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $subject,
        OrderInterface $order
    ) {
        /**
         * @var OrderAddressInterface  $billingAddress
         */
        $billingAddress = $order->getBillingAddress();

        $billingAddressExtensionAttributes = (null !== $billingAddress->getExtensionAttributes())?
            $billingAddress->getExtensionAttributes():
            $this->addressExtensionInterfaceFactory->create();
        $billingAddressExtensionAttributes->setDoorNo($billingAddress->getDoorNo());

        $billingAddress->setExtensionAttributes($billingAddressExtensionAttributes);

        if (!$order->getIsVirtual()) {
            $shippingAddress = $order->getShippingAddress();
            $shippingAddressExtensionAttributes = (null!== $shippingAddress->getExtensionAttributes())?
                $shippingAddress->getExtensionAttributes():
                $this->addressExtensionInterfaceFactory->create();

            $shippingAddressExtensionAttributes->setDoorNo($shippingAddress->getDoorNo());
            $shippingAddress->setExtensionAttributes($shippingAddressExtensionAttributes);
        }

        return $order;
    }
}
```

Create **di.xml** at `app/code/{Vendorname}/{ModuleName}/etc/`

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <type name="Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface">
        <plugin disabled="false" name="add_door_no_to_address" sortOrder="10"
                type="Vendorname\ModuleName\Plugin\Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

Comment: Hi But dont we need di.xml file to be updated?  Thanks in advance

Comment: off course. Di  XML is needed...

Comment: Sorry,  It is not working.

Comment: Am I missing anything

Comment: Are you  implementing this code to existing  any module?

Comment: from past 3 days I'm working on this no luck

Comment: [extension_attributes] => Array
(
[shipping_assignments] => Array
(
[0] => Array
(
[shipping] => Array
(
[address] => Array
(
 [address_type] => shipping
 [city] => w2retyu
 [company] => test
 [country_id] => test
 [customer_address_id] => 43766
 [customer_id] => 22738
 [email] => test@yopmail.com
 [entity_id] => 57356
 [firstname] => test
 [lastname] => test
 [parent_id] => 28678
 [postcode] => 2352
 [street] => Array
  (
   [0] => wert
  )

 [telephone] => 23456
)   This is the response i'm getting

Comment: Yes I'm implementing this in already overided sales module

Comment: <type name="Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface">
        <plugin name="vendor_add_order_extension_attribute"
                type="vendor\Sales\Plugin\Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryPlugin" />
    </type> is this correct

Comment: <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
    <extension_attributes for="Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderAddressInterface">
        <attribute code="door_number" type="string" />
    </extension_attributes>
</config>

Comment: <?php
namespace Vendor\Sales\Plugin\Magento\Sales\Api;

use Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderAddressExtensionInterfaceFactory;
use Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderAddressExtension;
use Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderAddressInterface;

class OrderRepositoryPlugin
{
    /**
     * @var OrderAddressExtensionInterfaceFactory
     */
    private $addressExtensionInterfaceFactory;

Comment: public function __construct(
        OrderAddressExtensionInterfaceFactory $addressExtensionInterfaceFactory
    ) {
        $this->addressExtensionInterfaceFactory = $addressExtensionInterfaceFactory;
    }

    public function afterGet(
        OrderRepositoryInterface $subject,
        OrderInterface $order
    ) {
        /**
         * @var OrderAddressInterface  $billingAddress
         */
        $billingAddress = $order->getBillingAddress();

Comment: $billingAddressExtensionAttributes = (null !== $billingAddress->getExtensionAttributes())?
            $billingAddress->getExtensionAttributes():
            $this->addressExtensionInterfaceFactory->create();
        $billingAddressExtensionAttributes->setDoorNumber($billingAddress->getDoorNumber());

        $billingAddress->setExtensionAttributes($billingAddressExtensionAttributes);

Comment: if (!$order->getIsVirtual()) {
            $shippingAddress = $order->getShippingAddress();
            $shippingAddressExtensionAttributes = (null!== $shippingAddress->getExtensionAttributes())?
                $shippingAddress->getExtensionAttributes():
                $this->addressExtensionInterfaceFactory->create();

            $shippingAddressExtensionAttributes->setDoorNumber($shippingAddress->getDoorNumber());
            $shippingAddress->setExtensionAttributes($shippingAddressExtensionAttributes);
        }

        return $order;
    }
}

Comment: I have updated the code and it is tested at 2.3.14 and it working fine

Comment: Still not working

Comment: ours is magento 2.3.2 EE version

Comment: [extension_attributes] => Array ( [shipping_assignments] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [shipping] => Array ( [address] => Array ( [address_type] => shipping [city] => w2retyu [company] => test [country_id] => test [customer_address_id] => 43766 [customer_id] => 22738 [email] => test@yopmail.com [entity_id] => 57356 [firstname] => test [lastname] => test [parent_id] => 28678 [postcode] => 2352 [street] => Array ( [0] => wert ) [telephone] => 23456 )

Comment: I  think it will work. Might some other issue  it is not called.

Comment: I copied the code again still not working

Comment: im not getting any issues durin compilation also

Comment: I just modified DoorNo to DoorNumber Because attribute code is door_number

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109155/discussion-on-answer-by-amit-bera-sales-order-address-custom-attribute-value-in).

Comment: any luck @poornima

Comment: Not working...tried same code

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
```

namespace Vendor\SalesGraphQl\Plugin\Magento\Sales\Api;

use Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderExtensionFactory;
use Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface;

class OrderRepositoryPlugin
{
/**
* @var OrderExtensionFactory
*/
private $orderExtensionFactory;

```
public function __construct(
    OrderExtensionFactory $orderExtensionFactory
) {
    $this->orderExtensionFactory = $orderExtensionFactory;
}

public function afterGet(
    OrderRepositoryInterface $subject,
    OrderInterface $order
) {
    $orderExtensionAttribute = (null !== $order->getExtensionAttributes()) ? $order->getExtensionAttributes() : $this->orderExtensionFactory->create();
    if (!$order->getIsVirtual()) {
        $shippingAddress = $order->getShippingAddress()->getData();
        $orderExtensionAttribute->setShippingAssignments([$shippingAddress]);
    }
    return $order;
}
```

}

> setShippingAssignments -> set value in setShippingAssignments method then only custom value will show in shipping address section of order Rest API.

For billing, you can set custom attribute via extension attribute. please try below code.

```
 $billingAddress  = $order->getBillingAddress();
        $billingAddressExtensionAttributes  = (null !== $billingAddress->getExtensionAttributes()) ?
            $billingAddress->getExtensionAttributes() :
            $this->orderExtensionFactory->create();
        $billingAddressExtensionAttributes->setCustomerNotes($billingAddress->getCustomerNotes());
        $billingAddress->setExtensionAttributes($billingAddressExtensionAttributes);
```